# ReactNative basic 'navigate' statement throwing app-crashing error: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working in ReactNaive 0.52 after upgrading, using Expo, and working to get previously functional navigation working.

I add this line of code as recommended by the ReactNative [navigation tutorial on RN-0.52](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.52/navigation.html):

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

When I click on the app to load I get the red screen of death with the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

When I comment out `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` the app reloads just fine.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

        static navigationOptions = {
                title: 'Home',
        };


        render() {
                // PROBLEM HERE (const {navigate...)
                // Loads when commented out. 
                // Fails when in not commented out.

                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

                return (
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <ScrollView style={styles.contianer}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:60}}>HomeScreen</Text>
                                <Button
                                        onPress={() => {
                                                navigate('DetailView');
                                        }}
                                        title="Title01"
                                        color="#841548"
                                />
                                <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Hello world!!!!!!!!!!</Text>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Hello world!!!!!!!!!!</Text>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <FloatingAction
                            actions={actions}
                            onPressItem={
                                    (name) => {
                                            console.log(`selected button: ${name}`);
                                    }
                            }
                        />
                </View>
        );
```

Comment: I tested it on expo and non expo app RN 0.52, everything worked, here the results [https://snack.expo.io/@yannerio/test-navigator]

Comment: What does your navigation code look like?